# Unknown math font

Tags: math-fonts

I am trying to identify the font used for the integral sign and letter x here:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that is not an `x`, but more likely a `\kappa`, similar to https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Greek_lowercase_kappa_variant.svg

Comment: do you have the pdf for that formula? (if so you can list the fonts exactly)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No. Just that picture.

Comment: Note that the kappa symbol is slanted after d, but it is unslanted after sin, cos. It seems that your picture is a result of typesetting work of an amateur.  The integral symbol is from bold variant of a math font but the rest isn't.

Comment: @wipet The upright kappa is from "NewTX" package (\upvarkappa).

Comment: @RobertW. My tip is that this is not TeX (i.e. no LaTeX, no latex package). There are slanted/unslanted version of kappa, the spaces between sin, cos and their arguments are missing, there is a mix of bond/nobold symbols. Of course, I am able to do such obscure things by TeX, but it is more complicated task:).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is the symbol `\varkappa` (you need the package amssymb).

Comment: which seems to look like ϰ and *ϰ* when slanted